# rails rest routes with multiple params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I use Refinery CMS blog module to create a simple blog, now I try to customize archive section, I want to add one more param for archive link, default route for archive looks like:

```
blog_archive_posts GET     /blog/archive/:year(/:month)(.:format)
```

now my question is how can I call this in rails and how can I provide the params for `blog_archive_posts_path`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<%= link_to "archive for #{year}/#{month}", 
            blog_archive_posts_path(year: @year, month: @month) %>
```

where `@year` and `@month` are defined in your controller appropriately